# Kubernetes Rook-Ceph: different pools for different use-cases?

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, rook

I'm experimenting with rook-ceph on kubernetes for storage again. I have 3 nodes, which each have

- a local ssd-partition mounted at `/dev/sda2`, and
- a NAS-volume at `/dev/sdb`.

In my rook-config, I use all devices, which automatically finds and uses both as OSDs. So far so good.

What I'd like to do is treat them as two separate storage classes in kubernetes - the ssd-pool is fast but small, while the NAS-pool is slow but huge. That way, I could attach IO-intensive pods like databases onto the ssd-storageclass, while size-heavy pods like fileservers would attach to the NAS-storageclass.

Since rook-ceph currently attaches all OSDs to the same pool, I can not target specific ones via a kubernetes storageclass:

```
bash-4.4$ ceph osd tree
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   TYPE NAME               STATUS  REWEIGHT  PRI-AFF
-1         0.82942  root default
-7         0.27647      host k8s-storage-1
 1    ssd  0.17879          osd.1               up   1.00000  1.00000
 5    ssd  0.09769          osd.5               up   1.00000  1.00000
-3         0.27647      host k8s-storage-2
 2    ssd  0.17879          osd.2               up   1.00000  1.00000
 3    ssd  0.09769          osd.3               up   1.00000  1.00000
-5         0.27647      host k8s-storage-3
 0    ssd  0.17879          osd.0               up   1.00000  1.00000
 4    ssd  0.09769          osd.4               up   1.00000  1.00000

bash-4.4$ ceph osd status
ID  HOST            USED  AVAIL  WR OPS  WR DATA  RD OPS  RD DATA  STATE
 0  k8s-storage-3   196M   182G      0        0       1       16   exists,up¹
 1  k8s-storage-1   374M   182G      0        0       0        0   exists,up¹
 2  k8s-storage-2   261M   182G      0        0       1       90   exists,up¹
 3  k8s-storage-2   121M  99.8G      0        0       0        0   exists,up²
 4  k8s-storage-3   187M  99.8G      0        0       0        0   exists,up²
 5  k8s-storage-1  85.3M  99.9G      0        0       0        0   exists,up²

¹local SSD storage
²remote NAS storage (it's just a 100gb for testing purposes)
```

I did find a possible solution, where I run two separate rook-ceph instances with a `deviceFilter`, so that one rook-ceph-cluster only uses the SSDs, while the other only uses the NAS-volumes. I dislike this solution due to the disadvantage of having to run two rook-ceph-cluster-instances in one kubernetes-cluster.

**Is there a way to get rook-ceph to separate the SSD- and NAS-storages, so that they can be independently targeted by kubernetes storage classes?**

---

**Update 1:** I found that I can update the storage classes for devices manually: `ceph osd crush set-device-class osd.XXX` - only thing I'm missing now is how to target them from a `kubernetes storageclass` via a `ceph pool`, in which (I guess?) the OSDs have to be put?

Best,
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LarsKumbier You can create cephcluster to specify deviceClasses for set of OSD'S https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/f70b687a6077877e29ab02b06a881ed2d65c3c78/Documentation/CRDs/Cluster/ceph-cluster-crd.md#osd-configuration-settings https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/f70b687a6077877e29ab02b06a881ed2d65c3c78/Documentation/CRDs/Cluster/ceph-cluster-crd.md#storage-class-device-sets  and use that deviceclasses for cephfs and rbd pools and create a storageclass to point to the rbd pool and cephfs data pools? this takes out the creation of multiple ceph clusters?